# Select one row with same id but different values in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

| ID | NAME | PURCHASE_DATE_1 | QUANTITY | AMOUNT | PURCHASE_DATE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 2024-05-23 | 5 | 4000 | NULL |
| 2 | DEF | 2024-06-21 | 2 | 5000 | NULL |
| 3 | ABC | NULL | 5 | 6000 | 2024-11-12 |
| 4 | DEF | NULL | 7 | 5600 | 2024-12-24 |
| 5 | EFG | 2024-06-21 | 7 | 5800 | NULL |
| 6 | POL | NULL | 1 | 6000 | 2024-12-24 |

I would like to select the NAME that occurs more than once with a different VALUE.

The output should be something like:

| ID | NAME | AMOUNT_1 | AMOUNT_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 4000 | 6000 |
| 2 | DEF | 5000 | 5600 |
| 3 | EFG | 5800 | NULL |
| 4 | POL | NULL | 6000 |

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (You can remove the unrelated tag.)

Comment: What is your actual RDBMS? MySQL and SQL Server are different database management systems.

Comment: Hints: Do a GROUP BY. Or a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: What if there are more than two occurrence of the same name having different values of amount. For example if "ABC" has occurrences having AMOUNT values as 4000, 600 and 8000. Then the number of columns will be 3 right? Is there any limit on number of occurrences of a particular Name with different values?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, 
CASE WHEN SUM(XX.AMOUNT_1) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM(XX.AMOUNT_1)END AS AMOUNT_1, 
CASE WHEN SUM(XX.AMOUNT_2) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUM(XX.AMOUNT_2)END AS AMOUNT_2
FROM
(
SELECT NAME, 
AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_1, 
0 AMOUNT_2 FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE PURCHASE_DATE_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, 
0 AMOUNT_1, 
AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_2 FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE PURCHASE_DATE_2 IS NOT NULL
)XX
GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming we only want to target 2 values per name, we can try the following pivoting approach with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    NAME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_2
FROM cte
GROUP BY NAME;
```